# Json object not escaped properly in bash

Tags: bash

This is my script

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
USERNAME="someUser"
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"auth":{ "client": $USERNAME, "password": "somePassword" }, "messages": { "UpdateProduct": {} }}' http://someDomain.com/services/json
```

it just becomes as below, it did not replace `$USERNAME` with `someUser`

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"auth":{ "client": $USERNAME, "password": "somePassword" }, "messages": { "UpdateProduct": {} }}' http://someDomain.com/services/json
```

but if i put USERNAME in, it works

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"auth":{ "client": "someUser", "password": "somePassword" }, "messages": { "UpdateProduct": {} }}' http://someDomain.com/services/json
```

Comment: Variables aren’t expanded within single quotes.

Answer (score 2):

Single quotes don't expand variables. You can use something like

```
 -d '{"auth":{ "client": '"$USERNAME"', "password"...
```

but it can still break if the username contains a double quote.

The cleanest way is to use a tool that understands JSON, e.g. `jq`:

```
$ USERNAME='"a"' jq '.username|=env.USERNAME' <<< '{"username":"..."}'
{
  "username": "\"a\""
}
```

Comment: `jq --arg u "$USERNAME" '.username|= $u' <<< '{"username": "..."}'` works as well. (Note you probably don't want the literal double-quotes in the resulting JSON.)

Comment: I wanted to demonstrate that `jq` properly escapes the doublequotes.